# How to call a function not defined in the project?

Tags: javascript, interop, typescript

Suppose you have the following:

```
class Foo {
  public bar(): void { baz(); }
}
```

Where `baz` is the function which exists in JavaScript code loaded into this page, but which does not exist in this project. How do I hint TypeScript compiler that the function just will be there?

(It's still too early to answer my own question, but I already figured that out, or so it seems):

```
declare function baz():void;
```

before the class definition should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Use ambient declaration :

```
declare var baz: any;
```

That will tell Typescript that `baz` exists somewhere.
You can also add params information and return type to have the IDE help

```
 declare var baz: (params: string) => string;
```